# How to extract variable from SOAP request in Edge policy?

Tags: apigee

Here's my policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ExtractVariables async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="extract-operation">
    <DisplayName>extract-operation</DisplayName>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>false</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <Source clearPayload="true">request.content</Source>
    <VariablePrefix>apigee</VariablePrefix>
    <XMLPayload stopPayloadProcessing="false">
       <Namespaces>
          <Namespace prefix="soapenv">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/</Namespace>
        </Namespaces>
        <Variable name="operation" type="string">
          <XPath>/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body</XPath>
        </Variable>
    </XMLPayload>
</ExtractVariables>
```

In trace tool I see that request.content resolves fine and shows the content, but I was expecting apigee.operation to be populated with the contents of .  What am I doing wrong?

**Fixed Policy:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ExtractVariables async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="extract-operation">
    <DisplayName>extract-operation</DisplayName>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>false</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <Source clearPayload="true">request.content</Source>
    <XMLPayload stopPayloadProcessing="false">
       <Namespaces>
          <Namespace prefix="soapenv">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/</Namespace>
        </Namespaces>
        <Variable name="operation" type="nodeset">
          <XPath>/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body</XPath>
        </Variable>
    </XMLPayload>
</ExtractVariables>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the Xpath you don't really need the scema and then you take on more variable out of the equation (ie whether the schema is valid). Then you could just reference //Body (or wherever it is in the xml)

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean, but I did get it figured out.  I needed to drop the variable prefix from the policy and change the variable type from `string` to `nodeset`.  Since you took the time to answer have an upvote and accept.